Выполнить пайтон код в exec
Возможно в exec, выполнить пайтон код в 2-3 строчки?
Через exec запускаю скрипты, глупо создавать пайтон скрипт ради 2-3 строчек...

Для того, чтобы выполнить код Питона надо иметь установленный Питон на компе. Это раз. Давайте вдумаемся в условие: мол, надо просто выполнить пару строчек кода, для чего не нужно писать скрипт. А что нужно для того, чтобы выполнить скрипт? Догадались? Написать код, да ещё сложнее и длиннее. Это называется "колоть орехи кувалдой".

тег php здесь зачем?

exec вызывается из под php

Достаточно посмотреть помощь по python
python3 --help

и легко находим
-c cmd : program passed in as string (terminates option list)

соответственно
$cmd = "python3 -c 'print(\"Hello world!\")'";
exec( $cmd, $output);
var_dump( $output );

результат
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  string(12) "Hello world!"
}

